# Max chosen of first or last elements of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

can u help me with this problem: :((

Given an array A[] have n positive numbers (n<=5000). Peter and Emma play a game chose number. When in turn of each person, they can choose the first or last elements of array then increase his/her score and remove that elements from array. Peter will play first.

You must find who can win and their score, and both Peter and Emma are the best players

Example:

**A = {4,5,1,3}**

At first turn, Peter can choose first number (4) or last number (3), so he choose **3** then remove it.

**// A= {4,5,1}**

At second turn, Emma can choose first number (4) or last number (1), so she choose **4** then remove it.

**// A={5,1}**

At third turn, Peter can choose first number (5) or last number (1), so he choose **5** then remove it.

**// A={1}**

At last turn, Emma only choose 1 number (1), then remove **1**

Now array is empty so the game is over, Peter have 3+5=8 score; Emma have 4+1=5 score. So Peter win.

Explain why not Peter have 9 score (4+5) and Emma have 4 scores (1+3). Because they are both best player so when Peter remove the number **3**, Emma will choose **4** instead of **1**\

**i have use backtrack but time limited**

Comment: Show the code you've written.

Comment: What kind of help do you expect?

Comment: This is a common DP problem, probably called something related to Coins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is the following:

Let us call `score(first, right)` the best score that a player can get with remaining element from `first` to `last` element.

Then, if player A select the `first` element, then player B will gain `score(first+1, last)`, and
player A will then gain `sum - player B score`.

The same logic is used if player A select the last element: player B will gain `score(first, last-1)`

This can be easily implemented in a recursive manner.

Memoization must be implemented to avoid repeating the same calculations.

Complexity: O(N^2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <tuple>

int sum;
int sum_left;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mem;

int score_rec (const std::vector<int> &A, int first, int last) {
    if (mem[first][last] >= 0) return mem[first][last];

    sum_left -= A[first];
    int score1 = A[first] + sum_left - score_rec (A, first + 1, last);
    sum_left += A[first];
    
    sum_left -= A[last];
    int score2 = A[last] + sum_left - score_rec (A, first, last - 1);
    sum_left += A[last];
    
    int score = std::max (score1, score2);
    mem[first][last] = score;
    
    return score;
}

std::tuple<int, int> scores (const std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    sum = std::accumulate (A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
    sum_left = sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        mem.emplace_back (std::vector<int> (n, -1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) mem[i][i] = A[i];

    int scoreA = score_rec (A, 0, n-1);
    int scoreB = sum - scoreA;
    
    return {scoreA, scoreB};
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> A = {4, 5, 1, 3};
    auto[scoreA, scoreB] = scores (A);
    std::cout << scoreA << " " << scoreB << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```